# When should I accept a parameter of Iterable<T> vs. Collection<T> in Java?

Tags: java, collections

What are the considerations of using [`Iterable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) vs. [`Collection<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) in Java?

For example, consider implementing a type that is primarily concerned with containing a collection of `Foo`s, and some associated metadata. The constructor of this type allows one-time initialisation of the object list. (The metadata can be set later.) What type should this constructor accept? `Iterable<Foo>`, or `Collection<Foo>`?

What are the considerations for this decision?

Following the pattern set forth by library types such as `ArrayList` (which can be initialised from any `Collection`, but *not* an `Iterable`) would lead me to use `Collection<Foo>`.

But why not accept `Iterable<Foo>`, given that this is is sufficient for the initialisation needs? Why demand a higher level of functionality (`Collection`) from the consumer, than what is strictly necessary (`Iterable`)?

Comment: There is a great article [here][1] about this.  


  [1]: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=119193

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Many of the collection types existed before [`Iterable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) (which was only introduced in 1.5) - there was little reason to add a constructor to accept `Iterable<T>` *as well as* [`Collection<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) but changing the existing constructor would have been a breaking change.

Personally I would use `Iterable<T>` if that allows you to do everything you want it to. It's more flexible for callers, and in particular it lets you do *relatively* easy filtering/projection/etc using the Google Java Collections (and no doubt similar libraries).

Comment: You say it would be a "breaking change."  What would break if (say) the ArrayList<T> constructor parameter was changed from Collection<T> to Iterable<T>?

Comment: @finnw: It would be source-compatible, but not binary-compatible: existing (compiled) classes using the current constructor would break (since they call the Collection-param-constructor explicitely) and need to be recompiled.

Answer (score 27):

An `Iterable` produces `Iterator` objects. An `Iterator` object, by definition, *iterates*. Notice, that the `Iterator` interface makes no promise as to how many times `next()` can be called before `hasNext()` returns `false`. An `Iterator` could possibly iterate over `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` values before its `hasNext()` method returns `false`.

However, a `Collection` is a special form of `Iterable`. Because a `Collection` cannot have more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements (by virtue of the `size()` method), it is naturally presumed that its `Iterator` objects will not iterate over this many elements.

Therefore, by accepting a `Collection` rather than an `Iterable`, your class can have some guarantee over how many elements are being passed in. This is especially desirable if your class is itself a `Collection`.

Just my two cents...

Comment: That disallows fairly *unreasonable* iterables at the expense of also disallowing non-collection, entirely reasonable iterables.

Comment: And, in fact, a `Collection` can also be larger than Interger.MAX_VALUE, then the size method just returns Integer.MAX_VALUE.  The advantage of a `Collection` is mostly the `size()` method (everything else can be implemented on top of Iterator and size, as AbstractCollection shows), so use a Collection **when you need the size before iterating**, not when you only want to iterate.

Comment: @Paŭlo: Wow, I didn't know that `Collection.size()` returns `Integer.MAX_VALUE` if it contains more than that many elements!

Comment: Yup! [Javadoc proof!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#size())

Answer (score 12):

Users of `Spring Data JPA` will find that the `Repositories` return collections of type `Iterable<T>.`

On projects I've worked on in the past that use `Spring`, I've found that the need to operate on a Collection after retrieval has often dictated that `Iterable<T>` is used in the business layer rather than `Collection<T>` in order to select an Object `T` from the collection.

All Collections are `Iterable` (that is the interfaces which extend the `Collection` interface, so not `Map`!), so using `Iterable` in the business layer is merely a case of referring to a Collection by its super type and still allows the use of `for-each` to iterate.

If you need to manipulate the contents of a collection, a convenience method would allow you to populate a new `Collection`, so you can make use of `contains()`, `remove()`, etc with the original collection data.

Alternatively, convenience methods are provided for this purpose by popular third party APIs such as Google Guava and Apache Commons.

Answer (score 9):

Use the most general interface that you can. Since all you're going to do is iterate, then I would say `Iterable` is the way to go (since it allows lazy iterators, etc.). You don't care where the iterator is coming from, so don't restrict it more than you have to.

Answer (score 4):

Some constructors, e.g. ArrayList(Collection c), use the toArray() method of Collection for efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

See "Why so much emphasis on Iterators and Iterables?" on the [Google Collection FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/wiki/Faq)
for a decent argument for preferring Iterators, especially when dealing with a lot of data. One analogy that might help is to think the difference between forward-only read-only cursors and scrollable cursors.

Answer (score 2):

If you go for Collection, then your class can be initialised from a collection only, if you go for Iterable, then you can initialise from either collection or iterable.

As the effort and performance for both is going to be the same, it makes total sense to accept Iterable in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

According to the principle of least surprise, you should emulate the Java collection pattern and take a Collection constructor arg.  It will make the people who come after you slightly less puzzled.

Comment: I disagree - Iterable still lets you take Collections as arguments, but as John says allows you to pass in other classes that let you step over their elements.  If this is all the functionality you need, it's a much better option.  Your Javadocs should document the argument anyway, and if the people coming after you are puzzled by core Java classes there are probably deeper issues. ;-)

Comment: I'm with Paul.  I hardly ever see Iterable, in our own classes or in libraries.  I see Collection more, and List most frequently.  I think there is logic behind the choice of Iterable, but I think current idiom is Collections.  Maybe it should be Iterables, and maybe it will be, someday, but for now, I would be less surprised by a Collection.

Answer (score -1):

You're correct, as it's considered good practice to ask for the most general form of what you need.