# Java: convert List<String> to a join()d String

Tags: java, string, list

JavaScript has `Array.join()`

```
js>["Bill","Bob","Steve"].join(" and ")
Bill and Bob and Steve
```

Does Java have anything like this? I know I can cobble something up myself with `StringBuilder`:

```
static public String join(List<String> list, String conjunction)
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   boolean first = true;
   for (String item : list)
   {
      if (first)
         first = false;
      else
         sb.append(conjunction);
      sb.append(item);
   }
   return sb.toString();
}
```

.. but there's no point in doing this if something like it is already part of the JDK.

Comment: See also this question for [lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150/whats-the-best-way-to-build-a-string-of-delimited-items-in-java)

Comment: Not strictly related but android has a built in join function as part of their TextUtils class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.Iterable)

Comment: Java 8 has a `String.join()` method. Have a look at this answer if you are using Java 8 (or newer) http://stackoverflow.com/a/22577565/1115554

Answer (score 957, accepted):

## `String.join`

With Java 8 you can do this without any third party library.

If you want to join a Collection of Strings you can use the [`String.join`()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) method:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");
String joined = String.join(" and ", list); // "foo and bar and baz"
```

## `Collectors.joining`

If you have a Collection with another type than String you can use the Stream API with the [joining Collector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-):

```
List<Person> list = Arrays.asList(
  new Person("John", "Smith"),
  new Person("Anna", "Martinez"),
  new Person("Paul", "Watson ")
);

String joinedFirstNames = list.stream()
  .map(Person::getFirstName)
  .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")); // "John, Anna, Paul"
```

The [`StringJoiner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) class may also be useful.

Comment: Unfortunately, String.join only accepts CharSequences and not as one would hope Objects. Not even sure if it's nullsafe

Comment: @Marc `assertThat(String.join(", ", Lists.newArrayList("1", null)), is("1, null"));`

Comment: StringJoiner is especially useful if one wants to join to something like `[a, b, c]` including the braces.

Comment: @Marc String.join also accepts `Iterable<CharSequence>`; Interface relationship: `Iterable -> Collection -> List`

Answer (score 309):

All the references to Apache Commons are fine (and that is what most people use) but I think the [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) equivalent, [Joiner](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html), has a much nicer API.

You can do the simple join case with

```
Joiner.on(" and ").join(names)
```

but also easily deal with nulls:

```
Joiner.on(" and ").skipNulls().join(names);
```

or

```
Joiner.on(" and ").useForNull("[unknown]").join(names);
```

and (useful enough as far as I'm concerned to use it in preference to commons-lang), the ability to deal with Maps:

```
Map<String, Integer> ages = .....;
String foo = Joiner.on(", ").withKeyValueSeparator(" is ").join(ages);
// Outputs:
// Bill is 25, Joe is 30, Betty is 35
```

which is extremely useful for debugging etc.

Comment: thanks for the plug!  Our Joiner also gives you the option to append directly to an Appendable (such as a StringBuilder, or any Writer) without creating intermediate Strings, which the Apache library seems to lack.

Comment: This is great, but can you please add a `.useForLastSeparator()` or some similar method?  That way, you could get something like ", and "  between only the last two items (with ", " for the rest).

Comment: Yes, it is thread safe. The only state saved in a joiner is the `separator` (which is `final`). Everything that I've seen in Guava, where I used to use an Apache Commons equivalent has been so much better (read: cleaner, faster, safer and just more robust in general) in Guava with fewer edge case failures and thread safety issues and smaller memory footprint. Their "best way possible" guiding principal seems to hold true so far.

Comment: If you need to go the opposite direction (i.e., splitting a String into pieces), check out the Guava class Splitter - also very well designed/implemented.

Comment: In Java 8, there is a `String.join()` method and a `StringJoiner` class.

Comment: Nice, but still reads strange: `useForNull("[unknown]")` should be `forNullUse("[unknown]")`, shouldn't it?

Comment: To skip blank values, use `Strings.emptyToNull` on your values: `final String a = Strings.emptyToNull( nameA.trim() );
return Joiner.on(" and ").skipNulls().join(a);`

Comment: Yup reads strange, the reverse would be more readable (since it is operating on the array) Joiner.on(names).skipNulls().join(" and ");

Answer (score 147):

Not out of the box, but many libraries have similar:

Commons Lang:

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(list, conjunction);
```

Spring:

```
org.springframework.util.StringUtils.collectionToDelimitedString(list, conjunction);
```

Answer (score 138):

On **Android** you could use **TextUtils** class.

```
TextUtils.join(" and ", names);
```

Comment: I was looking for this. `String.join` requires **min api level 26** on android.

Comment: brilliant one-liner, this answer must be on top

Answer (score 51):

No, there's no such convenience method in the standard Java API.

Not surprisingly, Apache Commons provides such a thing [in their StringUtils class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) in case you don't want to write it yourself.

Comment: It's always bugged me that String has a split but not a join.  In a way it makes sense that it does, but it's just annoying that there isn't at least a static method for it in String.

Comment: I'm with you Bemrose. At least they gave us an `isEmpty()` method instead of a (static) `join()` method in `String`... :rollseyes: :)

Answer (score 48):

Three possibilities in Java 8:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie")

String result = String.join(" and ", list);

result = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" and "));

result = list.stream().reduce((t, u) -> t + " and " + u).orElse("");
```

Answer (score 30):

With a java 8 collector, this can be done with the following code:

```
Arrays.asList("Bill", "Bob", "Steve").stream()
.collect(Collectors.joining(" and "));
```

Also, the simplest solution in java 8:

```
String.join(" and ", "Bill", "Bob", "Steve");
```

or

```
String.join(" and ", Arrays.asList("Bill", "Bob", "Steve"));
```

Answer (score 25):

I wrote this one (I use it for beans and exploit `toString`, so don't write `Collection<String>`):

```
public static String join(Collection<?> col, String delim) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<?> iter = col.iterator();
    if (iter.hasNext())
        sb.append(iter.next().toString());
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(delim);
        sb.append(iter.next().toString());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

but `Collection` isn't supported by JSP, so for TLD I wrote:

```
public static String join(List<?> list, String delim) {
    int len = list.size();
    if (len == 0)
        return "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(list.get(0).toString());
    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        sb.append(delim);
        sb.append(list.get(i).toString());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

and put to `.tld` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    <function>
        <name>join</name>
        <function-class>com.core.util.ReportUtil</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String join(java.util.List, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

and use it in JSP files as:

```
<%@taglib prefix="funnyFmt" uri="tag:com.core.util,2013:funnyFmt"%>
${funnyFmt:join(books, ", ")}
```

Comment: suggest changing `Collection<>` to `Iterable<>` ?

Comment: @JasonS +1. Good point, but read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159797/when-should-i-use-iterable-vs-collection-in-java

Answer (score 20):

Code you have is right way to do it if you want to do using JDK without any external libraries. There is no simple "one-liner" that you could use in JDK.

If you can use external libs, I recommend that you look into [org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class in Apache Commons library.

An example of usage:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Bill", "Bob", "Steve");
String joinedResult = StringUtils.join(list, " and ");
```

Answer (score 17):

An orthodox way to achieve it, is by defining a new function:

```
public static String join(String joinStr, String... strings) {
    if (strings == null || strings.length == 0) {
        return "";
    } else if (strings.length == 1) {
        return strings[0];
    } else {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(strings.length * 1 + strings[0].length());
        sb.append(strings[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < strings.length; i++) {
            sb.append(joinStr).append(strings[i]);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Sample:

```
String[] array = new String[] { "7, 7, 7", "Bill", "Bob", "Steve",
        "[Bill]", "1,2,3", "Apple ][","~,~" };

String joined;
joined = join(" and ","7, 7, 7", "Bill", "Bob", "Steve", "[Bill]", "1,2,3", "Apple ][","~,~");
joined = join(" and ", array); // same result

System.out.println(joined);
```

Output:

> 7, 7, 7 and Bill and Bob and Steve and [Bill] and 1,2,3 and Apple ][ and ~,~

Comment: giving a method parameter the same name as the method itself is probably not the best idea. `separator` would a lot more suggestive.

Answer (score 10):

#### Java 8 solution with `java.util.StringJoiner`

Java 8 has got a [`StringJoiner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) class. But you still need to write a bit of boilerplate, because it's Java.

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" and ", "" , "");
String[] names = {"Bill", "Bob", "Steve"};
for (String name : names) {
   sj.add(name);
}
System.out.println(sj);
```

Comment: You don't need to write a bit of boilerplate if you use the more convenient method [String.join()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...)).

Answer (score 9):

You can use the apache commons library which has a StringUtils class and a join method.

Check this link: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api.2.0/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Note that the link above may become obsolete over time, in which case you can just search the web for "apache commons StringUtils", which should allow you to find the latest reference.

(referenced from this thread)
[Java equivalents of C# String.Format() and String.Join()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187676/string-operations-in-java)

Answer (score 7):

You can do this:

```
String aToString = java.util.Arrays.toString(anArray);
// Do not need to do this if you are OK with '[' and ']'
aToString = aToString.substring(1, aToString.length() - 1);
```

Or a one-liner (only when you do not want '[' and ']')

```
String aToString = java.util.Arrays.toString(anArray).substring(1).replaceAll("\\]$", "");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will not append the conjunction of choice.

Comment: OOPS!! I am sorry, I didn't spot that.

Answer (score 7):

With java 1.8 stream can be used ,

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Bill","Bob","Steve").
String str = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" and "));
```

Answer (score 6):

A fun way to do it with pure JDK, in one duty line:

```
String[] array = new String[] { "Bill", "Bob", "Steve","[Bill]","1,2,3","Apple ][" };
String join = " and ";

String joined = Arrays.toString(array).replaceAll(", ", join)
        .replaceAll("(^\\[)|(\\]$)", "");

System.out.println(joined);
```

Output:

> Bill and Bob and Steve and [Bill] and 1,2,3 and Apple ][

---

A not too perfect & not too fun way!

```
String[] array = new String[] { "7, 7, 7","Bill", "Bob", "Steve", "[Bill]",
        "1,2,3", "Apple ][" };
String join = " and ";

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) array[i] = array[i].replaceAll(", ", "~,~");
String joined = Arrays.toString(array).replaceAll(", ", join)
        .replaceAll("(^\\[)|(\\]$)", "").replaceAll("~,~", ", ");

System.out.println(joined);
```

Output:

> 7, 7, 7 and Bill and Bob and Steve and [Bill] and 1,2,3 and Apple ][

Comment: Try it with "[Bill]", "1,2,3", and "Apple ][". Creative, but it has cases whwen it is incorrect.

Comment: Now try it with "~,~". You can't make a program with this kind of architecture completely bulletproof.

Comment: Yeah, I know... I've removed the downvote. But you should think a little more carefully about posting answers here, especially for questions like this one that are several years old. Not only are the answers immediately useful to the original poster, but they also show up on Google searches. (In fact, for questions that are several years old, new answers may have *no* value to the original poster.) Solutions that have drawbacks or errors can be harmful to people who find it later out of context.

Comment: I learn a lot here from others post like mine, with not perfect solution, but really rich of knowledge, and side thinking. Relax for others, each one must understand what each line of their code do. Remember programing is like an art, and even each line of code, means something about the programmer personality. And yes, I will not use this code in production!

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try Apache Commons StringUtils join method:

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join(java.util.Iterator, java.lang.String)

I've found that Apache StringUtils picks up jdk's slack ;-)

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

I also notice the  `toString()` underlying implementation issue, and about the element containing the separator but I thought I was being paranoid.

Since I've got two comments on that regard, I'm changing my answer to:

```
static String join( List<String> list , String replacement  ) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for( String item: list ) { 
        b.append( replacement ).append( item );
    }
    return b.toString().substring( replacement.length() );
}
```

Which looks pretty similar to the original question.

So if you don't feel like adding the whole jar to your project you may use this.

I think there's nothing wrong with your original code. Actually, the alternative that everyone's is suggesting looks almost the same ( although it does a number of additional validations )

Here it is, along with the  [Apache 2.0 license.](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)

```
public static String join(Iterator iterator, String separator) {
    // handle null, zero and one elements before building a buffer
    if (iterator == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
        return EMPTY;
    }
    Object first = iterator.next();
    if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
        return ObjectUtils.toString(first);
    }

    // two or more elements
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(256); // Java default is 16, probably too small
    if (first != null) {
        buf.append(first);
    }

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        if (separator != null) {
            buf.append(separator);
        }
        Object obj = iterator.next();
        if (obj != null) {
            buf.append(obj);
        }
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

Now we know, thank you open source

Comment: This will work now, but you can't be sure how List.toString() will behave in the future. I would never trust a toString() operation other than printing some informational string about the object in question.
In your defense, you're not the only one that proposes this solution.

Comment: What if the contents of an element in the list contains the substring `", "`?

Comment: @Hans & @Bart: You're right. I thought nobody else will notice :P  I'm changing my answer.

Comment: It depends on use case. For debugging purposes toString() is just fine IMO... provided you don't rely on particular formatting. And even so, if you write a tests for your code, any future changes will be caught.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) (formerly [GS Collections](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections)), you can use the `makeString()` method.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Bill", "Bob", "Steve");

String string = ListAdapter.adapt(list).makeString(" and ");

Assert.assertEquals("Bill and Bob and Steve", string);
```

If you can convert your `List` to an Eclipse Collections type, then you can get rid of the adapter.

```
MutableList<String> list = Lists.mutable.with("Bill", "Bob", "Steve");
String string = list.makeString(" and ");
```

If you just want a comma separated string, you can use the version of `makeString()` that takes no parameters.

```
Assert.assertEquals(
    "Bill, Bob, Steve", 
    Lists.mutable.with("Bill", "Bob", "Steve").makeString());
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 2):

Google's Guava API also has .join(), although (as should be obvious with the other replies), Apache Commons is pretty much the standard here.

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 does bring the

```
Collectors.joining(CharSequence delimiter, CharSequence prefix, CharSequence suffix)
```

method, that is nullsafe by using `prefix + suffix` for null values.

It can be used in the following manner:

```
String s = stringList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" and ", "prefix_", "_suffix"))
```

The  `Collectors.joining(CharSequence delimiter)` method just calls `joining(delimiter, "", "")` internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this from Spring Framework's StringUtils. I know it's already been mentioned, but you can actually just take this code and it works immediately, without needing Spring for it.

```
// from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.java

/*
 * Copyright 2002-2017 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
public class StringUtils {
    public static String collectionToDelimitedString(Collection<?> coll, String delim, String prefix, String suffix) {
        if(coll == null || coll.isEmpty()) {
            return "";
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<?> it = coll.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            sb.append(prefix).append(it.next()).append(suffix);
            if (it.hasNext()) {
                sb.append(delim);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, it is a variation of another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523871/best-way-to-concatenate-list-of-string-objects/524089#524089)

```
public static String concatStringsWSep(Iterable<String> strings, String separator) {
    Iterator<String> it = strings.iterator();
    if( !it.hasNext() ) return "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(it.next());
    while( it.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(separator).append(it.next());
    }
    return sb.toString();                           
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
java.util.Arrays.toString(anArray).replaceAll(", ", ",")
                .replaceFirst("^\\[","").replaceFirst("\\]$","");
```

Comment: Probably because the question calls for usage of a List versus an Array?  *shrug*

Comment: Because if you have a ", " in your strings it won't work.