# Convert List<String> to delimited String

Tags: java, string, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: convert List<String> to a join()d string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751844/java-convert-liststring-to-a-joind-string)

Having this:

```
List<String> elementNames = Arrays.asList("h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6");
```

What is an elegant way to get String with a custom delimiter, like so:

```
"h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6"
```

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. Made a quick search and seemed to miss it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you don't mind using the StringUtils library provided by apache, you could do:

```
// Output is "a,b,c"
StringUtils.join(["a", "b", "c"], ',');
```

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Comment: +1 for compactness, i'll do it that way

Comment: StringUtils.collectionToDelimitedString

Comment: And you can even pass in List and Iterable, not just arrays.

Answer (score 40):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(String s: elementnames) {
   sb.append(s).append(',');
}

sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1); //delete last comma

String newString = sb.toString();
```

Update: Starting java 8, you can obtain the same results using:

```
    List<String> elementNames = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");

    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",", "", "");
    elementNames.forEach(joiner::add);

    System.out.println(joiner.toString());
```

Comment: This is only if he minds using external libraries.  =)

Comment: Upvote for no external libraries - I am refactoring ancient code with "vintage" dependencies that are fixed.

Comment: The Java 8 version can be done on 1 line with Collectors. String joined = elementNames.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));