# How to print out all the elements of a List in Java?

Tags: java, list

I am trying to print out all the elements of a `List`, however it is printing the pointer of the `Object` rather than the value.

This is my printing code...

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

Could anyone please help me why it isn't printing the value of the elements.

Comment: What type did you declare the `List` to be?  Show us how you declared and instantiated it.

Comment: you have to call toString and youll get a explanation of the class or override the toString method for the type that the list contains

Comment: That's what you're telling it to print--you need a different toString or other readable string.

Comment: ArrayList<class> list= new ArrayList<class>();

Comment: Note that there's a more compact syntax you can use to accomplish the same thing:  `for (Object obj : list) {System.out.println(obj);}`.

Comment: Better to use `foreach` loop.

Comment: I feel this question is indirectly answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751844/java-convert-liststring-to-a-string) question, and more elegantly than the provided answers in this thread.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Here is some example about getting print out the list component:

```
public class ListExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Model> models = new ArrayList<>();

        // TODO: First create your model and add to models ArrayList, to prevent NullPointerException for trying this example

        // Print the name from the list....
        for(Model model : models) {
            System.out.println(model.getName());
        }

        // Or like this...
        for(int i = 0; i < models.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(models.get(i).getName());
        }
    }
}

class Model {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the introduction of the `Model` class related to the question?

Comment: It's just an assumption, since I don't know what kind of Object inside the list.

Answer (score 604):

The following is compact and avoids the loop in your example code (and gives you nice commas):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
```

However, as others have pointed out, if you don't have sensible toString() methods implemented for the objects inside the list, you will get the object pointers (hash codes, in fact) you're observing. This is true whether they're in a list or not.

Comment: What about only `list.toString()`.

Comment: Just using 'list.toString()' won't print the individual elements, unless it's a custom implementation of the List interface which overrides the normal behaviour (to print the class name and a hash code, more or less).

Comment: If they use custom class and does not override `toString`,your solution will also prints its class name and hash code.

Comment: It prints as [value1,value2,value3]. Can we able to print as without []?

Comment: Actually, @Jaskey is right - their answer is a better one. The `Arrays` method is helpful for arrays, but not now needed for subclasses of `AbstractCollection`.

Comment: From Java 1.2 every Collection has a decent `toString()`, no?
ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html?is-external=true#toString--

Answer (score 150):

Since Java 8, List inherits a default "forEach" method which you can combine with the method reference "System.out::println" like this:

```
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: @Katja Hahn, is it possible to append or prepend some string to `println` output?

Comment: @gumkins, YES, you can. Example: Arrays.stream(new String[] { "John", "Sansa", "Cersei" }).map(s -> "Hi " + s + "!").forEach(System.out::println);

Comment: Woah, Thanks for this!

Comment: For java/Android: 
Call requires API level 24 (current min is 21): java.lang.Iterable#forEach

Answer (score 60):

```
System.out.println(list);//toString() is easy and good enough for debugging.
```

**[`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29) of [`AbstractCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29)  will be clean and easy enough to do that**. `AbstractList` is a subclass of `AbstractCollection`, **so no need to for loop and no toArray() needed.**

> Returns a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the
>   order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets
>   ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma
>   and space). Elements are converted to strings as by
>   String.valueOf(Object).

If you are using any custom object in your list, say Student , you need to override its `toString()` method(it is always good to override this method) to have a meaningful output

See the below example:

```
public class TestPrintElements {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Element is String, Integer,or other primitive type
        List<String> sList = new ArrayList<String>();
        sList.add("string1");
        sList.add("string2");
        System.out.println(sList);

        //Element is custom type
        Student st1=new Student(15,"Tom");
        Student st2=new Student(16,"Kate");
        List<Student> stList=new ArrayList<Student>();
        stList.add(st1);
        stList.add(st2);
        System.out.println(stList);
   }
}


public  class Student{
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Student(int age, String name){
        this.age=age;
        this.name=name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "student "+name+", age:" +age;
    }
}
```

output:

```
[string1, string2]
[student Tom age:15, student Kate age:16]
```

Comment: Because this answer isn't entirely correct. It's using polymorphism without realizing it. Here's the actual inheritance hierarchy for `list`: `List -> Collection -> Iterable -> Object`. The class that actually inherits from AbstractCollection is `ArrayList`. So in this example when `toString()` is called it finds the `ArrayList` implementation which is defined in `AbstractCollection`. Note the inheritance hierarchy for `ArrayList`: `ArrayList -> AbstractList -> AbstractCollection -> Collection -> Iterable -> Object`

Answer (score 45):

Use `String.join()`
for example:

```
System.out.print(String.join("\n", list));
```

Answer (score 25):

The Java 8 Streams approach...

```
list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: same answer as Katja Hahn's

Comment: No it isn't.  Mine leverages stream().

Comment: @BradleyD what gains are realized by adding another layer of method calls there?

Answer (score 16):

The objects in the list must have `toString` implemented for them to print something meaningful to screen.

Here's a quick test to see the differences:

```
public class Test {

    public class T1 {
        public Integer x;
    }

    public class T2 {
        public Integer x;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return x.toString();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        T1 t1 = new T1();
        t1.x = 5;
        System.out.println(t1);

        T2 t2 = new T2();
        t2.x = 5;
        System.out.println(t2);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        new Test().run();
    }
}
```

And when this executes, the results printed to screen are:

```
t1 = Test$T1@19821f
t2 = 5
```

Since T1 does not override the toString method, its instance t1 prints out as something that isn't very useful. On the other hand, T2 overrides toString, so we control what it prints when it is used in I/O, and we see something a little better on screen.

Answer (score 15):

Consider a `List<String> stringList` which can be printed in many ways using **Java 8** constructs:

```
stringList.forEach(System.out::println);                            // 1) Iterable.forEach
stringList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);                   // 2) Stream.forEach (order maintained generally but doc does not guarantee)
stringList.stream().forEachOrdered(System.out::println);            // 3) Stream.forEachOrdered (order maintained always)
stringList.parallelStream().forEach(System.out::println);           // 4) Parallel version of Stream.forEach (order not maintained)
stringList.parallelStream().forEachOrdered(System.out::println);    // 5) Parallel version ofStream.forEachOrdered (order maintained always)
```

### How are these approaches different from each other?

**First Approach (`Iterable.forEach`)-**
The iterator of the collection is generally used and that is designed to be [fail-fast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#fail-fast) which means it will throw `ConcurrentModificationException` if the underlying collection is **structurally modified** during the iteration. As mentioned in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for `ArrayList`:

> A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or
>   more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting
>   the value of an element is not a structural modification.

So it means for `ArrayList.forEach` setting the value is allowed without any issue. And in case of concurrent collection e.g. `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` the iterator would be [weakly-consistent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#Weakly) which means the actions passed in `forEach` are allowed to make even structural changes without `ConcurrentModificationException`exception being thrown. But here the modifications might or might not be visible in that iteration.

**Second Approach (`Stream.forEach`)-**
The order is undefined. Though it may not occur for sequential streams but the specification does not guarantee it. Also the action is required to be non-interfering in nature. As mentioned in [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-):

> The behavior of this operation is explicitly nondeterministic. For
>   parallel stream pipelines, this operation does not guarantee to
>   respect the encounter order of the stream, as doing so would sacrifice
>   the benefit of parallelism.

**Third Approach (`Stream.forEachOrdered`)-**
The action would be performed in the encounter order of the stream. So whenever order matters use `forEachOrdered` without a second thought. As mentioned in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-):

> Performs an action for each element of this stream, in the **encounter
>   order of the stream** if the stream has a defined encounter order.

While iterating over a **synchronized collection** the **first approach** would take the collection's lock once and would hold it across all the calls to action method, but in case of streams they use collection's spliterator, which does not lock and relies on the already established rules of non-interference. In case collection backing the stream is modified during iteration a `ConcurrentModificationException` would be thrown or inconsistent result may occur.

**Fourth Approach (Parallel `Stream.forEach`)-**
As already mentioned no guarantee to respect the encounter order as expected in case of parallel streams. It is possible that action is performed in different thread for different elements which can never be the case with `forEachOrdered`.

**Fifth Approach (Parallel `Stream.forEachOrdered`)-**
The `forEachOrdered` will process the elements in the order specified by the source irrespective of the fact whether stream is sequential or parallel. So it makes no sense to use this with parallel streams.

Answer (score 15):

Or you could simply use the Apache Commons utilities:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toString-java.lang.Object-

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = ...
System.out.println(ArrayUtils.toString(myObjects));
```

Answer (score 12):

I have faced similar problems. My code:

```
List<Integer> leaveDatesList = new ArrayList<>();

.....inserted value in list.......
```

**Way 1: printing a list in a for loop**

```
for(int i=0;i<leaveDatesList.size();i++){
    System.out.println(leaveDatesList.get(i));
}
```

**Way 2: printing the list in a forEach, for loop**

```
for(Integer leave : leaveDatesList){
    System.out.println(leave);
}
```

**Way 3: printing the list in java 8**

```
leaveDatesList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what type of objects stored in the `List`, and whether it has implementation for `toString()` method. `System.out.println(list)` should print all the standard java object types (`String`, `Long`, `Integer` etc). In case, if we are using custom object types, then we need to `override` `toString()` method of our custom object.

Example:

```
class Employee {
 private String name;
 private long id;

 @Override
 public String toString() {
   return "name: " + this.name() + 
           ", id: " + this.id();
 }  
}
```

Test:

```
class TestPrintList {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Employee employee1 =new Employee("test1", 123);
     Employee employee2 =new Employee("test2", 453);
     List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList(2);
     employee.add(employee1);
     employee.add(employee2);
     System.out.println(employees);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is better implementation, to use `toString()` telling what fields in object you are interested in.

Comment: did not work until implemented toString as your answer. thanks

Answer (score 6):

1. You haven't specified what kind of elements the list contains, if it is a [primitive data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) then you can print out the elements.
2. But if the elements are objects then as Kshitij Mehta mentioned you need to implement (override) the method "toString" within that object - if it is not already implemented - and let it return something meaning full from within the object, example:

   ```
   class Person {
       private String firstName;
       private String lastName;

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

For a list of array of String

```
list.forEach(s -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString((String[]) s )));
```

Answer (score 5):

For loop to print the content of a list :

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("AA");
myList.add("BB");

for ( String elem : myList ) {
  System.out.println("Element : "+elem);
}
```

Result :

```
Element : AA
Element : BB
```

If you want to print in a single line (just for information) :

```
String strList = String.join(", ", myList);
System.out.println("Elements : "+strList);
```

Result :

```
Elements : AA, BB
```

Answer (score 4):

`System.out.println(list);` works for me.

Here is a full example:

```
import java.util.List;    
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HelloWorld {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Hello");
        list.add("World");
        System.out.println(list);
     }
}
```

It will print `[Hello, World]`.

Comment: Not different from other, earlier answers

Comment: I gave a full example with imports, class and main method which you can copy and paste and showed the result. Therefore, no reason to vote it down in my opinion

Answer (score 3):

```
    list.stream().map(x -> x.getName()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: What type has `x` and how is it related to the OP's question?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a dump function, which basicly prints out the public members of an object if it has not overriden toString(). One could easily expand it to call getters.
Javadoc:

> Dumps an given Object to System.out, using the following rules:
>
> - If the Object is Iterable, all of its components are dumped.
> - If the Object or one of its superclasses overrides toString(), the "toString" is dumped
> - Else the method is called recursively for all public members of the Object

```
/**
 * Dumps an given Object to System.out, using the following rules:<br>
 * <ul>
 * <li> If the Object is {@link Iterable}, all of its components are dumped.</li>
 * <li> If the Object or one of its superclasses overrides {@link #toString()}, the "toString" is dumped</li>
 * <li> Else the method is called recursively for all public members of the Object </li>
 * </ul>
 * @param input
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static void dump(Object input) throws Exception{
    dump(input, 0);
}

private static void dump(Object input, int depth) throws Exception{
    if(input==null){
        System.out.print("null\n"+indent(depth));
        return;
    }

    Class<? extends Object> clazz = input.getClass();
    System.out.print(clazz.getSimpleName()+" ");
    if(input instanceof Iterable<?>){
        for(Object o: ((Iterable<?>)input)){
            System.out.print("\n"+indent(depth+1));
            dump(o, depth+1);
        }
    }else if(clazz.getMethod("toString").getDeclaringClass().equals(Object.class)){
        Field[] fields = clazz.getFields();
        if(fields.length == 0){
            System.out.print(input+"\n"+indent(depth));
        }
        System.out.print("\n"+indent(depth+1));
        for(Field field: fields){
            Object o = field.get(input);
            String s = "|- "+field.getName()+": ";
            System.out.print(s);
            dump(o, depth+1);
        }
    }else{

        System.out.print(input+"\n"+indent(depth));
    }
}

private static String indent(int depth) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<depth; i++)
        sb.append("  ");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I happen to be working on this now...

```
List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(3, 4);
List<int[]> pairs = a.stream()
  .flatMap(x -> b.stream().map(y -> new int[]{x, y}))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());

Consumer<int[]> pretty = xs -> System.out.printf("\n(%d,%d)", xs[0], xs[1]);
pairs.forEach(pretty);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        answer(10,60);

    }
    public static void answer(int m,int k){
        AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(m);
        Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.generate(() -> n.incrementAndGet()).limit(k);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stream.toArray()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to override toString() method as you want that the element will be printend. 
so the method to print can be this:

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
    System.out.println(list.get(i).toString());
}
```

Comment: That's what the OP's code does. The call to `toString` is implicit.

Answer (score 0):

Solusion of your problem for java 11 is:

```java
String separator = ", ";
String toPrint = list.stream().map(o -> String.valueOf(o)).collect(Collectors.joining(separator));

System.out.println(toPrint);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

- for 2D(or more)

  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(list.toArray()));
- for 1D

  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()))

Answer (score 0):

one liner to print List

```
List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(0,1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums.toArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

System.out::println with forEach won't work in logger function when inside tomcat or just wanting information from a web application. Instead use:

```
for (Path path: myPaths ) {
    logger.warn( "Possible issue with path " + path.toString() );
}
```

Above example is purposely using path, just to show how to get the syntax working perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

```
   List<String> textList=  messageList.stream()
                            .map(Message::getText)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        textList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        public class Message  {

        String name;
        String text;

        public Message(String name, String text) {
            this.name = name;
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

      public String getText() {
        return text;
     }
   }
```