# Removing last comma or other delimiter when printing list to string

Tags: java, string

Let's assume that I have a `datastructure` with `n` elements `(0, 1, ... , n-1)`.

And assume these elements have some property I want to print (assume an `int`). And I want to print the `datastructure` on one line, with a delimiter (`comma`, `space`). So, the result would be something like this

`13, 14, 15, 16, 17`

What is the best way to add the comma and space (in Java)?

These are approaches I've taken:

1. If the `datastructure` is `Iterable`, iterate from `0 to n-2` and append the delimiter to each of those, then print the last element.
2. Loop through all elements and append everything to empty `String` (or `Stringbuilder`), then at the very end remove the last deliminator (`hardcoded`).

I feel like there's something better.

Edit: The question is unique. The 'possible duplicate' involves only printing, not messing with delimiters.

Edit2: Attempts as requested

```
// 1st approach
public void printStuff(ArrayList<Integer> input) {
    for (int i=0; i<input.size()-1; i++) {
        System.out.print(input.get(i) + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println(input.get(input.size()-1);
}
```

Another attempt

```
// 2nd approach
public void printStuff(ArrayList<Integer> input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<input.size(); i++) {
        sb.append(input.get(i)+", ");
    }
    sb.substring(0, input.size()-2);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: Please post code for your attempts.

Comment: If your list elements are custom objects, you can also alter their representation by overriding `Object#toString`.

Comment: Have a look at the code for Guava's `Joiner` class, see how it is implemented. Or `java.util.Arrays.toString`.

Comment: Or the Java 8 [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print out all the elements of a List in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168066/how-to-print-out-all-the-elements-of-a-list-in-java)

Comment: @AlvaroJoao It's literally a completely different question. The question you linked doesn't even address delimiters, simply printing on separate lines

Comment: it's amazing the triviality of problems one has to deal with in Java...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java 8's streaming APIs finally provide an elegant, native, way of doing this without resorting to ugly if-else structures or using third parties.

Assuming you have a list of `MyClass` objects, and assuming `MyClass` has a `getPropery()` access method that returns an `int`, you could do something like this:

```
List<MyClass> list = ...;
String concatination = list.stream()
                           .map(p -> String.valueOf(p.getProperty()))
                           .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks! Do you have a specific online resource where I can read up more on this?

Comment: @jiaweizhang [Oracle's tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html) are pretty decent.

Answer (score 1):

Using an iterator I would check whether there are any items left. 
If so, add a separator:

```
if (i.hasNext()) s.append(", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use some Java 8 Stream magic:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3) //just so we have a list to work on
String result = list.stream()
        .map(it -> it.toString())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a framework, like this:

https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html

Joiner.on(",").join(list)

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the first element, add it to your String and add `, <string>` to it:

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();

// add elements

StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
buffer.append(lst.remove(0));

for(String s : lst) {
    buffer.append(", ").append(s);
}
```

Comment: This is the same thing as I did for attempt 2 though backwards though it does take care of the hardcoded endpiece.