# Display elements from List - Double type

Tags: java

i have problem with display elements from list.

Button action:

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
      int lewy = Integer.parseInt(kresLewy.getText());
      int prawy = Integer.parseInt(kresPrawy.getText());
      licz(field.getText(),prawy,lewy);
   }
});
```

Here is my list:

```
 static public double licz(String wiersz, int lewy, int prawy) {
        double wynik = 0.0;
        ///////Lista podawana z klawiatury z krokiem co 1
        List<Double> listaX = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = lewy; i <= prawy; i++) {
            listaX.add((double) i);
        }
        System.out.println(listaX);



        try {

            StringReader tekstReader = new StringReader(wiersz);

            wykresy.parser parser_obj
                    = new wykresy.parser(new wykresy.MyLexer(tekstReader));

            TElement result = (TElement) parser_obj.parse().value;

            wynik = result.oblicz();

            System.out.println("WYNIK:" + wiersz + " = " + wynik);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Podczs obliczenia wystapil blad. (" + e.getMessage() + ")");
        } catch (Error error) {
            System.out.println("Podczs obliczenia wystapil blad. (" + error.getMessage() + ")");
        }
        //}
        return wynik;
    }
```

I think problem is in "lewy" and "prawy", because list is empty. How can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print out all the elements of a List in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168066/how-to-print-out-all-the-elements-of-a-list-in-java)

Comment: Please add `System.out.println(kresLewy.getText(), kresPrawy.getText())` in handle(). We need more context to answer to this! The title is also misleading, please change it.

Comment: the `licz` method must return something

Comment: Lewy: 1
Prawy: 5
List: []
here it is working. Method Licz() return "wynik" but List listaX is only element from method Licz().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your edit, the only problem is: lewy, prawy are switched, so your loop goes from 10 to 0 -> which results in an empty list.

You have several problems:

- lewy, prawy are switched
- licz does not return something
- wynik is unused

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int lewy = 0;
      int prawy = 10;

      licz("Text",lewy, prawy);
  }

  static public void licz(String wiersz, int lewy, int prawy) {
      double wynik = 0.0;
      List<Double> listaX = new ArrayList();
      for (int i = lewy; i <= prawy; i++) {
          listaX.add((double) i);
      }
      System.out.println(listaX);
  }
  ```

Comment: "According to your edit, the only problem is: lewy, prawy are switched, so your loop goes from 10 to 0 -> which results in an empty list." --- true omg -.- :D it is work...

Answer (score 3):

Just iterate through the list and print the values.

**Using foreach loop:**

```
    for(Double d: listaX){
        System.out.println(d);
    }
```

**Using functional operation:**

```
    listaX.forEach((d) -> {
        System.out.println(d);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print out something you can use `System.out.println(listaX)`, which prints the object to the console.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int lewy = 0;
    int prawy = 10;

    List<Double> listaX = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = lewy; i <= prawy; i++) {
        listaX.add((double) i);
    }
    System.out.println(listaX);
}
```

See this Post: [How to print out all the elements of a List in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168066/how-to-print-out-all-the-elements-of-a-list-in-java)