# Using .toString to display an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

After starting to write a this simple program I have encountered a logic error that I would love explained. The `toString()` method is currently printing `geographylist.GeographyList@15db9742`

Test Class-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    GeographyList g = new  GeographyList();


    g.addCountry ("Scotland");
    g.addCountry ("Wales");
    g.addCountry ("Ireland");
    g.addCountry ("Italy");

    System.out.println(g.toString());
```

ArrayList setup

```
public class GeographyList {

private ArrayList<String> countries;

public GeographyList(){
  countries = new ArrayList<>();
}

public ArrayList<String> getCountries() {
    return countries;
}

public String getCountry(int index){
    return countries.get(index);
}

public void addCountry(String aCountry){
  countries.add(aCountry);
  System.out.println(aCountry + " added.");
}
```

Comment: Implement `toString()` in your class for your desired output.

Comment: `g.toString()` will print the reference of `g` object

Comment: Thank you, spent ages looking at this for such an obvious mistake :) .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print out all the elements of a List in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168066/how-to-print-out-all-the-elements-of-a-list-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it prints `geographylist.GeographyList@15db9742` is because you are not printing an `ArrayList`. You are printing a `GeographyList`. A `GeographyList` may *contain* an `ArrayList`, but that's incidental.

The default implementation of `toString`, inherited from [the `Object` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html), is to print the package name `geographylist`, the class name `GeographyList` and the hash code `15db9742`.

If you want to override this behaviour, [you will need to override the behaviour of `toString`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java), just as the `ArrayList` class will have done itself.

That might look something like this:

```
public class GeographyList {
    //...

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return countries.toString();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, since you already have the ability to get the `ArrayList` from your class, you could call

```
System.out.println(g.getCountries().toString());
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(g.toString());
```