# Unable parse the json data in android even by following the actual procedure

Tags: android, json, rest, jsonparser

iam trying to parse the json data which is shown below.i got output for other Json response by following this procedure but for this i cant get data.

```
{
"totalResults": 7,
"startIndex": 1,
"hasMoreResults": false,
"itemsPerPage": 10,
"results": [
    {
        "offering_temp_id": {
            "displayName": "Cool Course",
            "id": "cours000000000004841",
            "course_no": "00006081",
            "version": null
        },
        "delivery_id": {
            "displayName": "Instructor-Led",
            "id": "eqcat000000000000004"
        },
        "student_id": {
            "id": "emplo000000006156648",
            "displayName": "Venkat Rao",
            "person_no": "VRAO"
        },
        "reg_no": "00008341",
        "wlist_on": "2017-08-17T08:59:39.843-0400",
        "wlist_priority": 5,
        "Max_Count": null,
        "Current_Count": null,
        "is_no_show": false,
        "is_walk_in": false,
        "offering_action_id": {
            "id": "ofapr000000000013441",
            "displayName": "00009081"
        },
        "class_id": {
            "id": "class000000000006981",
            "displayName": "Cool Course"
        },
        "elements_to_complete": 0,
        "status": "100",
        "id": "regdw000000000012581"
    },
    // total 7 fields
],
"facets": []
```

}

And iam using the parser procedure as follows

```
public class EnrollmentParser {
public ArrayList<EnrollmentData> getData(String respnose)//EnrollmentData is my pojo class contains 4 strings and its getters and setters
{
    ArrayList<EnrollmentData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(respnose);
        JSONArray array = mainObj.getJSONArray("results");
        for(int i = 0;i<array.length();i++)
        {
            EnrollmentData data = new EnrollmentData();
            JSONObject resObj = array.getJSONObject(i);
            data.setReg_num(resObj.getString("reg_no"));
            data.setElements_to_complete(resObj.getString("elements_to_complete"));
            data.setW_list_on(resObj.getString("wlist_on"));
            data.setW_list_priority(resObj.getString("wlist_priority"));
            dataList.add(data);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return dataList;
}
```

}

when iam trying to display the dataList returned from above method i didnt get any data i got response like

[image: This is the toast response of the dataList returned from method]

Suggest me any changes that are required to get the response

Answer (score 2):

There is no faulty parsing code, everything is fine (although better use `optString`).

By default , the toString function will return the type '@' reference value so

You need to override `toString` in `EnrollmentData` class to see the actual content inside `EnrollmentData` object

You can also collect your list objects as single string using

```
String str = Arrays.toString(yourList.toArray());
```

[How to print out all the elements of a List in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168066/how-to-print-out-all-the-elements-of-a-list-in-java)

Comment: Hai.. I have tries optString() but no change.And i didnt get the below toString() overriding and i didnt find any references to  can you tell me clearly?where i have to override that.

Comment: you have to override `toString` in `EnrollmentData` class https://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-toString()-method and for `optString` try reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java/40828056#40828056

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Gson to convert json into object easily instead of getting the field and set them one by one?

You may check out
https://github.com/google/gson