# Simple way to print List(String[]) Java

Tags: java

I've got such list:

```
List<String[]> rows = new CsvParser(settings).parseAll(new File("Z:/FV 18001325.csv"), "UTF-8");
```

What's the simplest way to print them to console?

I've tried

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rows));
```

And also:

```
String joined = String.join(",", rows);
System.out.println(joined);
```

But no use...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code of the other answer would print something like:

```
[[Ljava.lang.String;@4c873330, [Ljava.lang.String;@119d7047]
```

What you need is either:

```
rows.forEach(arr -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)));
```

which would print the output like this:

```
[a, b, c]
[d, e, f]
```

or

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(rows.toArray()));
```

which would print the output like this:

```
[[a, b, c], [d, e, f]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rows.toArray()));
```

Comment: Didn't you find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10168400/1100080)? If that is the case please reference to that answer

Comment: This will not print the desired output since it will call `toString()` on each array in the list. Use `Arrays.deepToString()` instead.