# How to print List<Object[]> value?

Tags: java, arrays, list, object, printing

I want to print all value in ls variable like this. All values ls is get from eight variable list like in the below code.

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook("D:/excel file/Mapping Prod Matriks _Group Sales Commercial.xlsx");
    com.aspose.cells.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);
    com.aspose.cells.Cells cells = worksheet.getCells();
    Range displayRange = cells.getMaxDisplayRange();
    List<String> ParaObjGroup = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> ParaObjCode = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> ParaProdMatrixId = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> ParaProdChannelId = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> ParaProdSalesGroupId = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> ParaCustGroup = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> ParaSlsThroughId = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> Active = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int row= displayRange.getFirstRow()+1;row<displayRange.getRowCount();row++){
        ParaObjGroup.add(displayRange.get(row,1).getStringValue());
        ParaObjCode.add(displayRange.get(row,3).getStringValue());
        ParaProdMatrixId.add(displayRange.get(row,5).getStringValue());
        ParaProdChannelId.add(displayRange.get(row,7).getStringValue());
        ParaProdSalesGroupId.add(displayRange.get(row,9).getStringValue());
        ParaCustGroup.add(displayRange.get(row,11).getStringValue());
        ParaSlsThroughId.add(displayRange.get(row,13).getStringValue());
        Active.add(displayRange.get(row,14).getIntValue());
    }


    List<Object[]> ls = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    for(int i=0;i<ParaObjGroup.size();i++){
        ls.add(new Object[]{ParaObjGroup.get(i),ParaObjCode.get(i),ParaProdMatrixId.get(i),ParaProdChannelId.get(i),
                ParaProdSalesGroupId.get(i),ParaCustGroup.get(i),ParaSlsThroughId.get(i),Active.get(i)});
    }


    System.out.println(ls);
```

But, when i run the result like this and i don't know yet what the meaning.

```
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@68b7b6ef, [Ljava.lang.Object;@754b3a9e, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1df5973b, [Ljava.lang.Object;@669bb1da, [Ljava.lang.Object;@77b993d6, [Ljava.lang.Object;@38990402, [Ljava.lang.Object;@45d63c55, [Ljava.lang.Object;@74131444, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1097b7e5, [Ljava.lang.Object;@58aa23e5, [Ljava.lang.Object;@a1abcdd, [Ljava.lang.Object;@61655659, [Ljava.lang.Object;@44081f03, [Ljava.lang.Object;@712c20d9, [Ljava.lang.Object;@820c09b, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1e450448, [Ljava.lang.Object;@451c227e, [Ljava.lang.Object;@3a1ca1a4, [Ljava.lang.Object;@2db833ca, [Ljava.lang.Object;@18502a39, [Ljava.lang.Object;@370410a7, [Ljava.lang.Object;@6be16028, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1970196d, [Ljava.lang.Object;@e955027, [Ljava.lang.Object;@6cc137eb, [Ljava.lang.Object;@13e5d15, [Ljava.lang.Object;@25510e56, [Ljava.lang.Object;@6c84433d, [Ljava.lang.Object;@5f5a9173, [Ljava.lang.Object;@330345ed, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1be3e4c5, [Ljava.lang.Object;@ec04fd1, [Ljava.lang.Object;@73b829e7, [Ljava.lang.Object;@3fc7380b, [Ljava.lang.Object;@30307ae3, [Ljava.lang.Object;@3ed3e5cc, [Ljava.lang.Object;@4993d44d]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print out all the elements of a List in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168066/how-to-print-out-all-the-elements-of-a-list-in-java)

Comment: Do your classes override the `toString` method?

Comment: You call `toString()` on the arrays in the `List`, and that is the default implementation from `Object`, just printing the class name (here the "code" `[L` for array) and the "address". So the output is expected (or: you got what you asked for …)

Answer (score 2):

because our list in collection from array when you want print values , they print is from object.
for print you can use of **forEach** and **Arrays.toString** so:

```
    ls.forEach((n)-> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n)));
```

Comment: i try your answer but there is a error. The error is "n cannot be resolve to variable". And my ide is Spring Tool Suite.

Comment: Perhaps your version of Java is pre Java 8.  You can check it using `java -version`.