# concatenate "List<SelectItem>" values to String as csv

Tags: java

I have some values in `List<SelectItem> selectedDividendYears`
Now I want to make a string concatenating all the values of this list as csv.

For **Example**:

```
selectedDividendYears = {'123', 'sdf234', '12 1234c'}
```

now I want only one string, which will look like -

```
"123, sdf, 12 1234c"
```

Comment: Check out this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751844/java-convert-liststring-to-a-joind-string

Comment: @Alex.Bullard: Actually I dont want for List<String>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache commons-lang, `StringUtils.join(selectedDividendYears, ',');`.

Comment: does the data type of selectedDividendYear matter ???means can i use this for any data type.

Comment: It would appear so. join has many different variations: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.util.Collection,%20char%29

Comment: please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811359/sort-items-of-richpicklist-target-table-automatically) and see if u can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
boolean first = true;
for (SelectItem item : selectedDividendYears) {
   if (first) first = false;
   else str.append(",");
   str.append(item.toString());
}

String outputString = str.toString();
```

Comment: please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811359/sort-items-of-richpicklist-target-table-automatically) and see if u can help me out.