# JavaScript: List Box not being updated after pop-up look up

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, seam

I currently have a listbox (part of a search criteria) that represents a list of strings that are retrieved one at a time via a pop-up window. However when the pop-up window closes the selected String is never added to the listbox.  (I have confirmed that the hidden variable is updated and if you navigate away from the page after a search is performed and navigate back, the list box correctly shows Strings I had selected from the pop up previously).  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function selectBook(bookId, extendedBookName) {
            var idInput = jQuery("#myForm\\:bookNames");
            if (idInput.val() == "") {
                idInput.val(extendedBookName);
            } else {
                idInput.val(idInput.val() + '@@@' + extendedBookName);
            }  
        }
    </script>
...
 <h:form id="myForm">
    ...
      <ui:define name="form-fields">
         <h:selectOneListbox id="booksListBox" size="3" style="width:470px">  
            <s:selectItems var="_var" value="#{bean.searchCriteria.bookNames}" label="#{_var}" noSelectionLabel="" />
         </h:selectOneListbox>
         <h:outputLink onclick="return openNewWindow('#{bean.booksLookupUrl}?#{bean.bookLookupParameters}', 'book');" 
                       target="_blank">
                     <h:inputHidden id="bookNames" value="#{bean.searchCriteria.bookNames}" converter="StringListConverter"/>
                     <h:outputText value="Add"/>
         </h:outputLink>

      </ui:define>
    ...
 </h:form>
```

This is javaScript that belongs to the lookup window.  This calls the selectBook function

```
function selectBook(bookId, extendedBookName) {
        var extendedName = unescape(extendedBookName);
        window.opener.selectBook(bookId, extendedName);
        window.close();
    }
```

And for my Java code...

```
public class BookSearchCriteria implements Serializable {
...
private List<String> bookNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getBookNames() {
    return bookNames;
}
public void setBookNames(List<String> bookNames) {
    this.bookNames = bookNames;
}
```

The StringListConverter code...

```
@FacesConverter("myStringListConverter")
public class StringListConverter implements Converter {

    // this is used as a regex, so choose other separator carefully
    private static final String MY_SEPARATOR = "@@@";

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(value.split(MY_SEPARATOR)));
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return "";
        }
        return join((List<String>) value, MY_SEPARATOR);
    }

    /**
     * Joins a String list, src: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1751844/149872
     * 
     * @param list
     * @param conjunction
     * @return
     */
    public static String join(List<String> list, String conjunction) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (String item : list) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                sb.append(conjunction);
            }
            sb.append(item);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure `selectBook` is being called? You don't show any event binding. Are you sure `idInput.length > 0` (e.g., the selector is correct)?

Comment: @user113215: Well it has a no selection label I think means it has some length.  I've confirmed through debugging that after you select a book from the lookup, it is indeed added to the list.  I've added the javaScript that call selectBook from the popup window.

Comment: If `idInput.length > 0` isn't true, it means jQuery can't find your `<select>` on the page (check this in debug). Is the popup window supposed to **add** new values? You can't use `.val()` to **add** a new item to the `<select>`, this only **changes** the selected `<option>`. To **add**, you need to create a new `<option>` element and append it to the `<select>`.

Comment: @user113215 The popup window appends a new value to the end of the bookNames (the hidden input variable).  Doesn't this by extension add a new '<option>' to listBox?

Comment: Ah, that's your problem. No, your server-side change in the popup window won't magically update the parent page until you reload it from the server. Of course you need to do this client-side if you want it to update immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand why you want to populate your listBox using a popup.

But if you modify the underlying bean values, you need to rerender the `<h:selectOneListbox/>` to reflect these changes. If you are using (or can use) the [richfaces framework](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/index.html) it can be done quite easily through an ajax call.

The [ajax4jsf](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/a4j/tld-summary.html) component called `<a4j:jsFunction/>` can do the job. For example in your parent page add :

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="refreshListbox" reRender="booksListBox" limitToList="true"/>
```

and in your popup just call this js function when a new book value is selected :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.opener.refreshListbox();
</script>
```

You could also use a `<rich:modalPanel>` instead of a popup to stay in the same page and interact more easily with your jsf components.

Answer (score 1):

The page in the popup window is running some **server-side** Java code that creates new options for the dropdown menu. This has no absolutely no effect on the parent page until the parent page is reloaded and regenerated by the **server**. To avoid reloading the page, you need to *create* and *select* the new option using **client-side** JavaScript/jQuery code.

Assuming that the HTML code for the resulting option should look something like `<option value="bookId">extendedBookName</option>`, you can use this:

```
<script>
function addBook(bookId, extendedBookName) {
    var newOption = jQuery('<option>').val(bookId).text(extendedBookName);
    var idInput = jQuery('#myForm\\:bookNames');
    idInput.append(newOption).val(bookId);
}
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5Cwjk/

Or, if the selection from the popup window is not guaranteed to be new, then you'll want to dynamically determine whether creating an option is necessary before doing so to avoid duplicates:

```
<script>
function addBook(bookId, extendedBookName) {
    var idInput = jQuery('#myForm\\:bookNames');
    if (idInput.val(bookId).val() != bookId) {
        var newOption = jQuery('<option>').val(bookId).text(extendedBookName);        
        idInput.append(newOption).val(bookId);
    }
}
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nTtY9/1/