# How to concatenate a String in Java without using a complex code structure?

Tags: java

I have the following java code:

```java
String strTest = null;

for (AlternativeEntity alternativeEntity : msg.Guidance()
      .getAlternatives()) {

    strTest = strTest + alternativeEntity.getArrivalStation().getName() + ", ";

}
```

The output looks like this:

```
nullabc, xyz, oop,
```

How can I solve this problem and very bad character format? It would be great if I can create output like this:

```
abc, xyz, oop
```

Comment: You could use a library like Guava. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751844/java-convert-liststring-to-a-joind-string

Comment: You should use StringBuilder for this nor String.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize `strTest` as:

```
String strTest = "";
```

Also, remove the last comma `,`

```
strTest=strTest.substring(0, strTest.length()-1);
```

Comment: Or use Guava, which can do all the stuff for you in a single line. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [Joiner#join(Iterable parts)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html#join%28java.lang.Iterable%29). For example:

```
Joiner joiner = Joiner.on(", ").skipNulls();
String result = joiner.join(list);
System.out.println(result);
```

Here, all the elements of the list will be printed comma separated **without** any trailing commas. Also, all the `null` elements will be skipped.

More info:

- [Strings Explained](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained)

Comment: That's what I wanted to answer. +1

Comment: having a separate library just to join the lines together seems like an overkill. Also, if we're going to use libraries, is there some reason to use Guava instead of [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.String%29)? `StringUtils.join(list, ", ");` seems simpler than this example.

Comment: I haven't said Guava is the best. It's just an option. Also, I would say using Guava is an overkill - it's just an utility library. :)

Answer (score 3):

Initialize your string to "":

```
 String strTest = "";
```

Alternatively, you should use a StringBuilder:

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

 for (AlternativeEntity alternativeEntity : msg.Guidance()
  .getAlternatives()) {

     builder.append(alternativeEntity.getArrivalStation().getName()).append(", ");

 }
```

This will produce better performance.

Comment: Why the boilerplate? Why don't you use Guava for example.

Comment: Also remove the last `,` after the loop. Your answer is the best, but nobody paid attention to that detail.

Comment: Maybe also include about removing the trailing `", "`.

Answer (score 1):

Java provides StringBuilder class just for this purpose,its simple and easy to use..

```
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("India ");

     //to append "Hi"
    str.append("Hi");

    // print the whole string
    System.out.println("The string is "+str)
```

*the output will be* : The string is **India Hi**

[click here to know more about StringBuilder class](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/stringbuilder_tostring.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Replace String strTest = null; by String strTest = "";

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 String strTest = null;
```

to

```
String strTest = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use:

```
String strTest = "";
```

and at the end:

```
if(strTest.endsWith(", "))
   strTest = strTest.substring(0, strTest.length()-2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `String strTest="";`

For skipping the last  comma','
Use outside For loop:

```
strTest = strTest.substring(0,strTest.trim().length()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String strTest = null;

for (AlternativeEntity alternativeEntity : msg.Guidance().getAlternatives()) {
  String name = alternativeEntity.getArrivalStation().getName();
  strTest = (strTest == null) ? name : strTest +  ", " + name;
}
```

If the list is long, you should use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)  rather than the `String` for `strTest` because the code above builds a fresh string on each iteration: far too much copying.