# Convert a list of Patterns into Predicates using stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am trying to convert a list of patterns (whose type is `string`) into predicates and for some reasons my brain keeps ending up with something close to the following code:

```
    List<Predicate> predicates = patterns.stream()
        .map(Pattern::asPredicate)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

which obviously doesn't compile. What's the best way of writing the conversion stream?

This is the error message I am getting:

```
Provider.java:32: error: method map in interface Stream<T> cannot be applied to given types;
            .map(Pattern::asPredicate)
            ^
  required: Function<? super String,? extends R>
  found: Pattern::a[...]icate
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
      method asPredicate in class Pattern cannot be applied to given types
        required: no arguments
        found: String
        reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  where R,T are type-variables:
    R extends Object declared in method <R>map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)
    T extends Object declared in interface Stream
MsisdnPartitioningProvider.java:32: error: invalid method reference
            .map(Pattern::asPredicate)
                 ^
  non-static method asPredicate() cannot be referenced from a static context
Note: MsisdnPartitioningProvider.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
```

Comment: What error you are seeing ?

Comment: "*obviously doesn't compile*" ?!? it does compile assuming `List<Pattern> patterns` and involved classes being from standard library: `java.util.List`, `java.util.function,Predicate`, `java.util.regex.Pattern`, `java.util.stream.Collectors` (and it being inside a method or using `jshell`) - PLEASE provide a [mre]

Comment: is `patterns` eventually a `List<String>` (not a `List<Pattern>`)? If so, you need `.map(Pattern::compile)`  just after `stream()`  - Or even worse, a Raw Type? - I hate this guessing... everything would be much easier having a [mre]

Comment: **Don't use *raw type*s.** `Predicate` expects a *type argument* to be given. Change `List<Predicate>` to `List<Predicate<String>>`.

Comment: @Sandah Aung  Please share what is type of `patterns`

Comment: the type of patterns is `string`

Comment: Updated answer @SandahAung, please check and let us know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned that `patterns` are String, i.e. it might be `List<String>`, so you might want to try below:

```
List<Predicate> predicates = patterns.stream().map(Pattern::compile).map(Pattern::asPredicate)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: you can use `List<Predicate<String>>` to avoid `raw type` warning as user @MC Emperor mentioned

Comment: The compiler is complaining about a different problem now `Provider.java:36: error: invalid method reference .map(Pattern::asMatchPredicate)`

Comment: Above suggestion is provided based on what you have said, `patterns` are `Strings` meaning,  something like this; `List<String> patterns = new ArrayList<>();`
If your `patterns` are different please let us know exact type.

Comment: Patterns are indeed strings. 

        `List<String> patterns = Arrays.asList(rawPatterns);`

Comment: @SandahAung - updated Answer, please let us know if it works,

Comment: The problem I think is a little more subtle: `non-static method asPredicate() cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: @SandahAung , I am not getting `non-static method asPredicate() cannot be referenced from a static context` error when I tried.

Comment: I think what I want to achieve is more similar to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882927/using-streams-to-convert-a-list-of-objects-into-a-string-obtained-from-the-tostr)