# Why still get [ ] after using toString method?

Tags: java, stack, tostring

Here is my code:

```
public class StackStudy{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Stack<String> st = new Stack<String>();
        st.push("hi");
        st.push("bye");
        st.push("awful");
        System.out.println(st.toString());
    }
}
```

and console prints out this:

```
[hi, bye, awful]
```

I thought using toString will get rid of the [], why is it still there?

EDIT:
If toString is not the proper way to get rid of[], what is the right way to do it?

Comment: Why did you think `toString` would get rid of the brackets?

Comment: It's the default implementation.

Comment: [It is hard coded in the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.toString%28%29). A proper way? Create an own method that prints the content.

Comment: Remove it using `String#substring`. It's not that hard if you try it.

Comment: Do you want a programmatic way to do it, i.e. iteration, or do you want the brackets to be removed?

Comment: @AlexisKing because I want to print out a string and so far I have only learned toString. what is the right way to get rid of the []?

Comment: Don't use toString() to rely on a specific output format

Comment: If you don't like the `toString()` implementation in `Stack`, you can always make your own subclass which has its own implementation.

Comment: I would opt for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22577565/1065197) in the dup Q/A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `toString()` method of `Vector` (or possibly `AbstractCollection`) includes the brackets (and `Stack` inherits that `toString()`). You could remove them by taking the substring like

```
String str = st.toString();
System.out.println(str.substring(1, str.length() - 1));
```

Comment: The brackets are from `AbstractCollection`, not `Vector` :P.

Answer (score 0):

overriding toString() gives you full control over what get's returned. Therefor, you can skip the brackets. However, you've only called the toString() method (which is actually what the System.out.println() is actually doing as well. Therefor, the outcome is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The following code would do the trick.

```
public class StackStudy{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Stack<String> st = new Stack<String>();
        st.push("hi");
        st.push("bye");
        st.push("awful");
        String stackAsString = st.toString();
        System.out.println(stackAsString.substring(1, stackAsString.length() - 1));
    }
 }
```

Comment: tried but not working, not sure I understood this part:    String stackAsString = st.toString();
        System.out.println(stackAsString.substring(1, stackAsString.length() - 1));