# How to expand a range \w\d+-\w\d+

Tags: java

I have some String type data like "`U39,R11,U50-U55,U99`".

How I change it to "`U39,R11,U50,U51,U52,U53,U54,U55,U99`" by expanding the hyphenated range?

I tried use a Java regular expression to grasp the number and letter prefix before the "-" and after the "-", and then use the loop to print the numbers from start to end. Is there a better solution?

Comment: what if you have `X50-A11` ?

Comment: Is the title a pun that I don't get?  I think it would benefit future users to change it to something like “How to expand a range of labels?”

Comment: @5gon12eder "pun": LOL. - If I translate literally from my 1st language I'd probably come up with "bonding stroke". And a frenchman might produce  "line of union".

Comment: @laune I thought it might be a military reference where the symbols label the various battleships or whatever in the “striker's front line”.  Maybe they use this kind of syntax to describe their strategies?

Comment: @5gon12eder Not bad, but US Navy hull numbers *contain* a hyphen (DD-69).

Comment: no the example of X50-A11, the letter prefix before the number is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a sensible way would be to proceed like so:

1. Split the string into an array (call it `labelsIn`) of strings using [`String.split(",")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-).
2. Create an `ArrayList<String>` (call it `labelsOut`) to hold your results.
3. Loop over the `labelsIn` array and for each element:

   - If it [matches the pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--) `[A-Z][0-9]+`, append it to the `labelsOut` list.
   - Else, if it matches the pattern `([A-Z])([0-9]+)-\1([0-9]+)` (call the [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) object `match`), extract the numbers `low` and `high` (using `Integer.valueOf(match.group(2))` and `Integer.valueOf(match.group(3))`) and for all numbers `n` from `low` to `high`, add [`String.format("%s%d", match.group(1), n)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) to the `labelsOut` list.
   - Else it is a syntax error.
4. [Concatenate the strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751844/java-convert-liststring-to-a-joind-string) from the `labelsOut` list with a `","`.

You can generalize the regular expressions a bit by allowing zero or more white-space characters (`\s*`) around the `","` and `"-"` if you see fit.

Note that the above procedure is optimized for didactic clarity, not performance.  You can get rid of some of the intermediate results if you want.  You might also consider using Java 8 [streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) to “streamline” the code.

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure the meaning of String.format("%s%d", match.group(1), n), what is the output?

Comment: `match.group(1)` returns the matched character (the thing inside the first pair of parenthesis in the regex), for example `"U"`.  `String.format` replaces the `%s` with the string it is passed as argument #1 and the `%d` with the representation of the integer passed as argument #2.  Therefore, if `n = 51`, the formatted string would read `"U51"`.  Try it out to see.

Comment: sorry for respond late， do I need to loop all numbers n from low to high as you said.

Comment: Sure, if you want them in the list as you show in your example with `low = 50` and `high = 55`.  You'll end up with something like `for (int n = low; n <= high; ++n) { labelsOut.add(String.format("%s%d", match.group(1), n)); }`.

Answer (score 0):

There are, of course, various ways you could do this. I would think that using regular expressions is a pretty straightforward approach. Streams of items in a list like this are a pretty good use case for Java 8 streams (rather than traditional iteration):

```
class Expander {
    private final List<String> expandedList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([UR])(\\d+)-[UR](\\d+)");

    public static String expand(String input) {
        return Arrays.stream(input.split(",")).parallel()
            .collect(Expander::new, Expander::accept, Expander::combine)
            .expandedList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    }

    private void accept(String item) {
        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(item);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            int from = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
            int to = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
            IntStream.rangeClosed(from, to)
                .mapToObj(i -> matcher.group(1) + i)
                .forEach(expandedList::add);
        } else {
            expandedList.add(item);
        }
    }

    private Expander combine(Expander other) {
        expandedList.addAll(other);
        return this;
    }
}
```

My test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Expander.expand("U23,R45,U12-U15,R7");
}
```

Prints out `U23,R45,U12,U13,U14,U15,R7`

Comment: Thank you for your respond.  I have never seen the method to use the streams as so.

Comment: it is much better indeed!

Comment: @BaochengLi great I'm pleased you found it useful. Streams are very powerful and quite intuitive once you get used to them.

Comment: @BaochengLi I'd appreciate it if you could accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: sorry for respond late, the line IntStream.rangeClosed(from, to) .map(i -> matcher.group(0) + i).forEach(expandedList::add); it has syntax errors in eclipse.  Another question, is the initial the input String need to expand?

Comment: Yes `initial` is the input string. Could you tell me the syntax errors you get? I wrote a test programme myself for this and it worked fine so it might be an issue with Eclipse (I use NetBeans)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Could you please share your test program? I copied the class expander to eclipse,  the errors are Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
 - Syntax error on token ":", EnhancedForStatementHeaderInit expected after 
  this token
 - Syntax error on token "-", -- expected

Comment: Sure I'll post the test code. Though it sounds to me like you are not using Java 8.

Comment: @BaochengLi I realised I made a few errors retyping the Expander into my answer - I've corrected that. However it does not explain your syntax errors which all sound like the compiler not understanding Java 8 syntax.

Comment: I will try to use Java 8. is there method not to use loop to solve my question by using java 7?