# Java ArrayList StringBuilder appending

Tags: java, arraylist, stringbuilder

I have one problem when appending List values as String. I will be getting 1 or more than 1 value into the list. Then I need to append these string as one string and use a separator , for each string. But at the end also the comma is getting added. How Can I remove this at the end of the string dynamically. Here is my code:

```
cntList = parseXml(metadata.xml);
if (cntList.size() != 0) {
    // entryCountryMap.put(id, country);
    System.out.println("Size is  ---->" + cntList.size());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (cntList.size() >= 2) {
        for (String s : cntList) {
            sb.append(s);
            sb.append(",");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("StringBuilder ----->" + sb.toString());
}
```

And my output is like this:

```
StringBuilder ----->All Countries,US - United States,
```

Please help me resolving this. Thanks - Raji

Comment: What you are looking for is called Joining a string. This is explained here: [Java: convert List<String> to a joined string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751844/java-convert-liststring-to-a-joined-string)

Answer (score 6):

With java 8 it's a one liner

```
String.join(",", cntList);
```

If you need to filter the elements of the list and/or mutate the strings before joining to a single string, you can still do it in a very concise manner without loops.

```
cntList.stream().filter(...).map(...).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

(the `...` need to be replaced by your filtering predicate and your mapper)

Comment: Nice **one line** solution +1

Comment: There is nothing telling Java 8 is being used. Also, if Java 8 is available, a `String.join()` is superior for this particular situation.

Comment: @ Simon - Using java 6 version. So I tried the other solution which is working. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Or, more compactly, `String.join(",", cntList);`.  See [String.join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-).

Answer (score 3):

I would use normal `for` loop. The last one append outside the for loop without comma

```
if (cntList.size() >= 2) {
    for (int i=0;i<cntList.size()-1;i++) {
        sb.append(cntList.get(i));
        sb.append(",");
    }
    sb.append(cntList.get(cntList.size()-1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply delete the last character:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("foo,");
System.out.println(sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1));
```

**Output**

`foo`

More dynamically, you can find the last comma by index and delete that plus anything that comes after:

```
sb.delete(sb.lastIndexOf(","), sb.length());
```

As [Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo) points out:

`sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);` will actually perform better than `sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1)`.

Comment: From what I remember `sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1)` will need to create new copy of old values without last element. It would be faster to simply set reduce length of builder `sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);`

Comment: @Pshemo nice thinking. Will add to the answer.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. `setLenght` will call `ensureCapacityInternal` which will try to expand array if new capacity is larger, but this is not the case here since we want to reduce it.