# Alternate to String.join to concatenate

Tags: java, mysql, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am inserting a key value pair to hashmap in the below code.

```
HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
    result.put("Description", "true";
    result.put("System Menu Program", "false");
    result.put("User ID Code", "false");
    result.put("User ID Version", "true");
```

And i am trying to iterate the result to be printed by joining multiple output string . currently i am using String.join to join the results which contains false as value but the problem i am facing here is i need to use any alternate to String.join because String.join method has been released in java 1.8 but our server is using 1.6 is there a alternate way to replace this below function

```
List<String> a1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String key : result.keySet()) {
       if (result.get(key).contains("false")){
           a1.add(result.get(key));
           finalResult = String.join(" // ", a1 );
       }
    }
    System.out.println(finalResult);
    return finalResult;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751844/java-convert-liststring-to-a-joind-string

Comment: @Santhosh did the answer resolve ur query?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apache common's [StringUtils.join](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join(java.lang.Iterable,%20char)), which internally iterates and concatenate.

Alternatively, have your own implementation that will iterate and join.