# Printing an arraylist with an enhanced foor loop - error: cannot find symbol and variable already defined in method

Tags: java, arraylist

I am new to java and am trying to write a method that will print out an ArrayList using an enhanced for loop. Whenever I compile, the fore loop gives me the following errors:

> error: cannot find symbol
>
> error: variable list2 is already defined in
>      method printLists(ArrayList,ArrayList)
>            for(String list2: list)

```
public static void printLists(ArrayList <String> list1, ArrayList <String> list2 )
{
    System.out.println("list1.txt contains:");
    for(String list1: list)
        System.out.println(list1+ " ");

    System.out.println("list2.txt contains:");
    for(String list2: list)
        System.out.println(list2+ " ");
}
```

Can someone please explain to me what these errors mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of the for-each loop is incorrect:

```
for(String list1: list)
```

Two problems with this line:

1. As error says you are trying to define a new variable names `list1` of type `String` but you already have such a variable name in the scope.
2. There is nothing defined as `list`. Basically the syntax is that: `for(#item : #collection)`

You are looking for something like

```
for(String item : list1)
```

Read more on [How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/85190/6400526)

---

A nicer way to print list will be to use `String.join` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22577565/6400526)

```
System.out.println(String.join(" ", list1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and clarification! I'll check out the link and accept it once the time lock is gone :).

Comment: @starlight - you are welcome :) Let me know how it goes :)

Answer (score 1):

You've swapped `list` and `list1` (and `list2`) in your `for-each` loops. However, I would first suggest you program to the `List` interface. And assuming you are using Java 8+, I would prefer to `stream()` the contents and join them with a `Collector`. Like,

```
public static void printLists(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
    System.out.printf("list1.txt contains: %s%n", list1.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
    System.out.printf("list2.txt contains: %s%n", list2.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
}
```

**or** possibly make the arguments [variadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) and generic (so it can take any number of `List`s of any type) like

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <T> void printLists(List<T>... lists) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("list%d.txt contains: %s%n", i + 1,
                lists[i].stream().map(Object::toString).collect(
                        Collectors.joining(" ")));
    }
}
```