# How to separate until last element of ArrayList in android

Tags: android, string, arraylist

I need to assign an ArrayList's data into a String variable.

Using following code I am getting `tempSeats` equals `jack, ravi, mike,`

```
 ArrayList<String> userSelectedSeats = new ArrayList<String>();
   userSelectedSeats.add("jack");
   userSelectedSeats.add("ravi");
   userSelectedSeats.add("mike");

   for (String s : userSelectedSeats) {
     tempSeats += s + ", ";
   }
```

but output should be `jack, ravi, mike` What modification should I do to my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the for loop with this,

```
tempSeats = TextUtils.join(", ",userSelectedSeats);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

Let Java's streams do the heavy lifting for you:

```
String tempSeats = userSelectedSeats.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're adding a comma after the end of every item, even the last item. You only want to add a comma if the item isn't the *last* item in the list. This is called *joining*.

If you're using Java 8, you can do

```
userSelectedSeats.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
```

Otherwise see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751844/java-convert-liststring-to-a-string) for further info.

Comment: Woooow, that Stream thing is awesome, didn't know about it. Looks like LINQ but in Java, although more limited.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `String.join` will accomplish the task at hand.

```
String result = String.join(", ", userSelectedSeats);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String c;

  ArrayList<String> userSelectedSeats = new ArrayList<String>();
       userSelectedSeats.add("jack");
       userSelectedSeats.add("ravi");
       userSelectedSeats.add("mike");

       for (int i=0; i < userSelectSeats.length(); i++)
        c += userSelectSeats.get(i).toString()+ ",";
```