# Android sqlite select query where clause with Array values

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a string array and I want to query by where clause with string array.

[image: code]

Comment: You need to transform your array into this string: `(1,4,16,18,20)` before using it in the query string.

Comment: Now you made your question even worse. Add the code again in a well formatted manner

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22577565/575376

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build a string of comma separated values from the array, not pass the array.

Assuming

```
    String[] getAnswerIds = new String[]{"1","4","16","18","20"};
    boolean after_first = false;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s: getAnswerIds) {
        if (after_first) {
            sb.append(",");
        } else {
            after_first = true;
        }
        sb.append(s);
    }
    String your_list_of_values = sb.toString();
```

Then your_list_of_values will be the string **1,4,16,18,20** you then just need to place that string in the appropriate place within the query.

e.g.

```
    Cursor mycursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE ID IN(" + your_list_of_values + ")",null);
```

Comment: Really Thanks MikeT

Comment: Just use `TextUtils.join(",", array)`