# unexpected String.join() behavior

Tags: java, java-8

I tried to print contents of a `List<String>` with a "**,**" in between them. Followed the book Functional Programming in Java by Venkat Subramaniam, on page **54** , he did exactly what I am doing but my print result is coming as a single string without a comma`(,)`.

```
String[][] deepArrayStr = new String[][]{{"Alex", "nullpointer"}, {"Eran", "George"}};
 List<String> str= Arrays.stream(deepArrayStr)
     .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
for(String s:str){
    System.out.print(String.join(",",s));
}
```

**Output**: `AlexnullpointerEranGeorge`

**Expected**: `Alex,nullpointer,Eran,George`

---

I tried another way and it works fine, I just wanted to know is there anything that I am doing wrong in the above approach whereas in the book Venkat also did the same thing that I am doing?

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.stream(deepArrayStr)
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

**Output**: `Alex,nullpointer,Eran,George`

**Expected**: `Alex,nullpointer,Eran,George`

My question is not to convert from `List` to `string` but to add delimiter while printing.

Comment: please see Venkat's example , and correct me if i have done anything different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: convert List<String> to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751844/java-convert-liststring-to-a-string)

Comment: Note that you can also join the strings using a collector: `.collect(Collectors.joining(","))`. Of course, the resulting object will be `String` instead of `List<String>`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're iterating over the list, and calling `String.join` with a single entry each time. That's never going to use the delimiter.

To make this clear, consider these two examples:

```
String x1 = String.join(",", "a");
String x2 = String.join(",", "a", "b");
```

Then the value of `x1` will be "a", and the value of `x2` will be "a,b". `String.join` only adds the delimiter *between* items - so if you only pass it a single item, it doesn't need to add any delimiters.

You can just remove your `for` loop, and replace it with:

```
System.out.println(String.join(",", str));
```

Comment: sir, i wonder why in loop each time the delimiter is not getting added??

Comment: @CommonMan: Because you're only passing in a single string. If you call `string.Join(",", "foo")` the result is always just "foo".

Comment: @CommonMan: I've edited my answer to clarify the behavior of String.join with a single element.

Answer (score 11):

```
System.out.print(String.join(",",s));
```

You are passing a single `String` to each `String.join` call, so of course it won't add any delimiter. It only adds the delimiter (comma in your case), if you pass multiple `String`s.

If, for example, you'd collect your `Stream` into a `String` array instead of a `List`, you can pass that array to `String.join`:

```
String[] str = Arrays.stream(deepArrayStr)
                     .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                     .toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println (String.join (",", str));
```

This will output:

```
Alex,nullpointer,Eran,George
```

Comment: You can pass a list into `String.join` as well - there's an overload accepting an `Iterable<Charsequence>`

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the comment. I missed that overload.

Answer (score 5):

Though the answers already highlight the difference and the fix possible, this is just to make it more functional in comparison:

Your first block of code can be transformed as:

```
Arrays.stream(deepArrayStr)
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .map(s -> String.join(",", s)) //map each string 'if possible' joined by delimeter ,
        .forEach(System.out::print); //print the above mapped string
```

while on the other hand the latter simply does this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(deepArrayStr)
    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","))); //join strings and collect to print (after that)
```

Reference to [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...)) and its relevant implementation and [`Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining(java.lang.CharSequence)) and its functionality.