# Output the contents of an ArrayList as a comma-separated String

Tags: java

I am attempting to add a comma separator to the String representation of a Java ArrayList but nothing seems to work, I am obviously missing something simple.

Sadly old Java 6 (running in a JSP):

```
ArrayList zones= new ArrayList();
zones.add(pageContext.getAttribute("zone"));

for(int i=0; i<zones.size(); i++)
out.println(zones.get(i));

// output is   CellA116 CellA116 CellA116 Reception Reception CellA11

StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
for(int i=0; i<zones.size(); i++)
{
stringBuffer.append(zones.get(i));
stringBuffer.append(",");
}

out.println(stringBuffer.toString());

// output is   CellA116,CellA116,CellA116,Reception,Reception,CellA11,  (commas)

  %>     

</tr>
</c:forEach>

syntax wont work here (outside of loop)
out.println(stringBuffer.substring(0, stringBuffer.length() - 1));
```

I  need to remove the final comma (as I eventually want to use the array in chart.js), appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: `zones.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\s]", "")`? [Demo](https://ideone.com/upkheP)

Comment: If you can use Java 8, take a look at this: https://ideone.com/43GQlC

Comment: See this answer which also addresses the JSp context: [Java: convert List<String> to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751844/java-convert-liststring-to-a-string/15837355#15837355)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: convert List<String> to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751844/java-convert-liststring-to-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, relying on a `toString()` method to do this is an easy way to inadvertently introduce bugs later on. If you change what concrete class is providing the collection (maybe to a `Set` instead of a `List` for example), your assumption that it starts and ends with square brackets might be untrue, and your output might change without you realising it.

I'd suggest that a more appropriate solution would be to iterate over the collection of Strings and add them to a `StringBuilder`.

So, it might look something like:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<strList.size(); i++)
{
    stringBuilder.append(strList.get(i));
    stringBuilder.append(",");
}

// Remove the last character from the StringBuilder to avoid a trailing comma.
String commaSeparatedList = stringBuilder.substring(0, stringBuilder.length() - 1);

out.println(commaSeparatedList);
```

Comment: I changed it to StringBuffer and that seems to work (commas included) but the substring attempt removes all the commas

Comment: `StringBuffer` should be fine too - see the first line of the [`StringBuilder` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for information about the difference.

Comment: Oh! You will need to have the `.substring` line outside the loop (i.e. after the loop has finished), if you have it inside the loop, that would remove the commas as you describe.

Comment: Thanks again, the loop is a jstl c:forEach loop so I have to fugure out how to do the substring outside of that loop

Comment: original edited (perhaps I can 'transfer' the array to javascript and then strip the last comma there, though I have been trying to 'transfer' the java ArrayList to javascript (in the same jsp) for over a week now and this seems to be beyond me.

Comment: It's a long time since I've done JSP, and I remember getting between Java-land and JS-land being difficult (although achievable) - probably worth a separate question here. As for the edit - I'm not sure I'm following - is the `for` loop part normal Java within `<% %>` tags, which themselves are wrapped with `<c:forEach>` tags? Or have you only edited the question to show the end of the for loop (i.e. the `</c:forEach>`)?

Comment: the forEach loop is large and is the output of a sql select first put into c:set variables which then end up in ArrayList zones, that part is working. 'transferring' java to javascript in the same jsp just confuses me but then I am a newbie. I appreciate your help, have been struggling with the basics for over a week.

Comment: just some tips,in jsp forEach I guess there has a method to get the current count for the loop,if the count is not equal the size of the list,append comma. So the last comma will not show

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize a `StringBuilder` and a classic `for` loop to output a *csv* line from `List<String>`.

Have a look at this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<String> zones = new ArrayList<String>();
    zones.add("CellA116");
    zones.add("CellA116");
    zones.add("CellA116");
    zones.add("Reception");
    zones.add("Reception");
    zones.add("CellA11");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < zones.size(); i++) {
        if (i < zones.size() - 1) {
            sb.append(zones.get(i)).append(";");
        } else {
            sb.append(zones.get(i));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

The output will look like this:

```
CellA116;CellA116;CellA116;Reception;Reception;CellA11
```

If you want to have a method with a flexible separator `char`, then use something like this:

```
public static String toSeparatedString(List<String> values, char separator) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        if (i < values.size() - 1) {
            sb.append(values.get(i)).append(separator);
        } else {
            sb.append(values.get(i));
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this  if (i < values.size() - 1) causes an issue (either results in no output or strips all commas if already inserted)

Comment: @Ralph this is for a `List<String>` that has no commas inserted before but It will not strip out anything. How are you using it? The `if` statement just determines if the currently handled `String` is the last one and if it is, there will be no trailing separator character. That's the only purpose of it.

Answer (score -2):

I dont see the need for another for loop to replace the [] and , zones.toString().replaceAll("[\[\]\s]", "") suggested by Lino works well.