# Convert list into String with values

Tags: java

I use this code to return a list from REST endpoint:

```
private String getCurrencies(Integer id) {      
    List<CurrencyDTO> list = null;
    try {
        list = StreamSupport.stream(currenciesService.getCurrencyByContractID(Integer.valueOf(id)).spliterator(), false)
                   .map(currencies_mapper::toDTO)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list.toString();
}
```

DTO:

```
public class CurrencyDTO {

    private Integer id;

    private Integer contract_id;

    private String code;
    ...
}
```

How I can get a list of values from code values? Something like that:

```
String list = "code, code, code, code, code";
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751844/java-convert-liststring-to-a-string

Answer (score 2):

If you implement `toString()` of `CurrencyDTO` to simply return the `code`, then `list.toString()` will return `[code, code, code, code, code]`

Otherwise use streams:

```
list.stream().map(CurrencyDTO::getCode).collect(Collectors.join(", "))
```