# How to join when using map with filter with stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to create a query if the `getData()` return `"yes"`. So added the filter for the same.

Now if the value of `getData()` is `"yes"` then I want to concat the three parameter which I am getting from the object.

Now for the list of object I want to join all the value which is coming from

```
(f -> f.getF()+" "+f.getO()+" "+f.getV())
```

with " and " as delimiter but not able to figure it out.

```
String query = data.stream()
    .filter(f -> f.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
    .map(f -> f.getF()+" "+f.getO()+" "+f.getV())
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" and","how to do this" , suffix));
```

for example,
we are getting data from that object as

> f.getF()--------"column name"

> f.getO()--------"="

> f.getV()--------"2"

so I want to add all the condition with and delimiter and produce a single String with all the conditions.

I think I can append "and" in the  map() and later remove the last "and" from the string

something like this

> columnname = 2 and columnnam1 > 1 and column2 = 6

Comment: You mean like `Collectors.joining("\"")`?

Comment: I think you need to add an example with the values of `getF()`, `getO()`, `getV()`, and the expected output.

Comment: let me add that

Comment: Did you try this `Collectors.joining(" and ")` ?

Comment: `.map(f -> f.getF()+" and "+f.getO()+" and "+f.getV())` ?

Comment: Then all you need is a simple `Collectors.joining(" and ")`. No need for rocket science here.

Comment: bro , I am still learning, sometimes you know the concept but missed on the side how to apply the same :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: convert List<String> to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751844/java-convert-liststring-to-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `F` is a column name, `O` is an operator and `V` is a value and if you need to get expression like `column1 = 1 and column2 > 2 and ...` then you just need to use `Collectors.joining(" and ")`:

```
String query = data.stream() // stream1 - original stream of the data collection
    .filter(f -> f.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) // stream2 - contains only elements with "yes"
    .map(f -> f.getF()+" "+f.getO()+" "+f.getV()) // stream3 - stream of the strings produced by expression f.getF()+" "+f.getO()+" "+f.getV()
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" and "));
```

**Some explanation.**
Here the `.collect(Collectors.joining(...))` joins the elements of the stream produced by the previous `.map(f -> f.getF()+" "+f.getO()+" "+f.getV())` call.

There are 3 different streams created:

```
String query = data.stream() // stream1 - original stream of the data collection
    .filter(f -> f.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) // stream2 - contains only elements with "yes"
    .map(f -> f.getF()+" "+f.getO()+" "+f.getV()) // stream3 - stream of the strings produced by expression f.getF()+" "+f.getO()+" "+f.getV()
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" and","how to do this" , suffix));
```

So, first you join `f.getF()`, `f.getO()` and `f.getV()` with `" "` joiner as follows:

```
.map(f -> f.getF()+" "+f.getO()+" "+f.getV())
```

You'll get the stream of the string like

```
"F1 O1 V1",
"F2 O2 V2",
...
```

Tis stream will be joined by `.collect(Collectors.joining(...));`. For example, using `.collect(Collectors.joining(" and "));` will produce string like

```
"F1 O1 V1 and F2 O2 V2 and ..."
```

Comment: Updated the answer to make it more structured and to address the updated question.

Comment: Hi , just need little help, what is the best way to check if the f is not null, another filter before f->f.getData="yes" ?

Comment: Hi, you can use `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` for that. If you need to check `getData()` result for nullability, then use `.filter(f -> f != null && f.getData() != null)`

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there:

```
String query = data.stream()
    .filter(f -> f.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
    .map(f -> f.getF() + " " + f.getO() + " " + f.getV()))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" and "));
```

Which will produce something like this:

```
columnName1 = 2 and columnName2 > 5
```