# In list find lenghtOfArgument with lambda in Java

Tags: java, list, lambda

In my taks I need to find size() of argument and for every object print size.
Object of type Car are in Set(so this maybe should help)

I did this:

```
List<Integer> numberOf = cars
.stream
.map(car->car.getNumbers().size())
.collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(numberOf);
```

Output is : [1,1,1,1]

I need output like this:

Audi - 1
Bmw - 1
Porsche - 1
Bentley - 1

If I go with

```
for(Car c: cars)
sout(c.getName + numberOf)
```

It gets me Audi [1,1,1,1]
Bmw[1,1,1,1]etc.

How to properly print all those values.
I also tried to Override method toString in class car but I also get the same output.

Edit:
Class Car

```
public Car(String name, List<Colours> colours)
super(name);
this.colours= colours;
```

Comment: What is "sout"?

Comment: System.out.println @NomadMaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want output like "name - number", perhaps generate strings:

```
List<String> combined = cars
.stream
.map(car->car.getName + " - " + car.getNumbers().size())
.collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(combined);
```

Comment: This is the one! Tnx for helping

Comment: Do you know how to remove [] because it gives me a string and commas

Comment: @sdavb That's how Java prints out a list by default. See this answer for possible next steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22577565/7916438

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is:

```
    cars.forEach(car -> 
            System.out.println(car.getName() + " - " + car.getNumbers().size()));
```

Grouping by name:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;


Collection<Car> cars = ...// your cars
final Map<String, Long> grouped = 
    cars.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(car -> car.getName(), counting()));
System.out.println(grouped);
```

Comment: I need to include map

Comment: It says no instance of type(s) of type variable (R) exist so that void confronts to R

Comment: if you need only print forEach is enough

Comment: use grouping that I'd added into the answer

Comment: I need to use map after stream() not Map