# Print elements of a List in columns

Tags: java

I created this little method to make taking a list return a string with all the elements.
But I wanted to add the fact that it returned me in column, for example:

```
Hello
to
All
```

I tried to insert the "\ n" but it doesn't change the result.

```
    public static String fromListToString(List list) {
    String string= "";
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        string+= "\n" + list.get(i);
    }
    return string;
}
```

How can I do?

Comment: How did you run this? How do you print the output? `\n` sould work in most systems.

Comment: While you're at it, why not simply [join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1751844/205233) your strings with the newline char? As for your problem at hand: I'd try including the carriage return like so `"\r\n"`.

Comment: Hi @Filburt I don't understand, could you give me an example related to my code?

Comment: @Jacket Have you tried the solution in the post I linked?

Comment: BTW that function can (almost **¹**) be simplified to `String.join("\n", list)`, or using the system line separator: `String.join(System.lineSeparator(), list)` || **¹** missing the leading new line

Comment: Also note: it seems you are using **raw types** here, as you don't specify that you have a `List<String>` here. And `list` is a terrible name for a variable. Rather say what you EXPECT to be in that list, like `elementNames` or something like that. The IDE can tell you the type of the variable, there is no point in hard-coding the TYPE in the name!

Comment: @GhostCat You're right, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Please tell us: How did you run this? How do you print the output? On which system? And what is the exact output you are seeing?

Comment: @Hulk I am starting it in AEM, for the title component, to have a title in column and not for horizontal, it is a simple GetTitle method that is invoked

Comment: @Hulk The problem is definitely AEM, thanks for the replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works on my system (eclipse on windows), but to make it platform independent you can use [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = List.of("Hello", "to", "all");
    System.out.println(fromListToString(list));
}

public static String fromListToString(List<?> list) {
    String string= "";
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        string +=  System.lineSeparator() + list.get(i);
    }
    return string;
}
```

One thing I also fixed: note the `List<?>` instead of the rawtype `List`. This does not cause any problems here, but it might later on if you reuse this somewhere.

Ouput:

```
Hello
to
all
```

(there is a leading blank line because of the first `\n`).

If you are still seeing the output in a single line, this is probably due to the way you print the result. Some loggers, for example, remove all linebreaks from messages. If you are writing the result to a file, you may need to make sure the correct line separator for your system is used, see [How do I get a platform-dependent new line character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/how-do-i-get-a-platform-dependent-new-line-character)

Comment: The result instead of the string is a copy error, I have updated the code! Sorry for my mistake

Comment: When you know that hardcoding the newline is bad, why are putting up example code that does it the bad way?

Comment: Yeah well, that's the point: maybe don't invest a lot of time in answering unclear questions. Rather tell the OP to look out for [mcve] and improve the question. *Guessing* what might be going on isn't the ideal option.

Comment: @GhostCat agreed. I sometimes still fall into that trap.

Comment: I thought it was an error in my code, instead it is due to some configuration of Aem, thanks to everyone for the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String fromListToString(List list) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        result += "\n" + list.get(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Matter of typo. :)
Your String was called string, and not result.

New answer:

Use:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

Instead of:

```
\n
```

The linebreak character is not "\n" on every operating system.

Comment: The result instead of the string is a copy error, I have updated the code! Sorry for my mistake

Comment: No problem. Look at the answer now, I updated it.

Comment: Same, I can only wrap if I insert a very long string

Comment: Just for security (no bad thoughts): Do you run the method? And what is exactly the output? Do you have another method, which has an nearly exact name?